# XeLaTeX/graphics specials

Tags: xetex, pdf

When I use the following code under XeLaTeX

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{foo.pdf}}
```

the XDV file contains the following opcodes:

```
PUSH
XXX "pdf:btrans"
XXX "x:scale 0.99667 0.99667"
PUSH
PUSH
PUSH
PUSH
PUSH
PUSH
XXX "pdf:btrans"
XXX "x:scale 1 1"
PUSH
PUSH
XXX "pdf:image matrix 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 page 0 pagebox cropbox (foo.pdf)"
POP
POP
XXX "pdf:etrans"
POP
POP
POP
POP
POP
POP
XXX "pdf:etrans"
POP
```

Where can I find a description of the specials with namespace `x` and `pdf`?

I guess that `pdf:btrans` keeps the current graphic state in memory and starts a new one, is the `x:scale` a special specific to XeLaTeX?

Why is there first a 0.99667 scale (obtained from the `\resizebox`) and then *another one* with 1.0 scale?

In the `pdf:image` special I see a `matrix` key word that reminds me of the PostScript graphic state matrix, why is this matrix not used for the scaling? I looked in my document and all figures had the same "unitary" matrix, under which circumstances would this matrix be different?

And final question: I see that, contrarily to PostScript specials like

```
PSfile=%0022fig1.eps%0022 llx=0 lly=0 urx=104 ury=131 rwi=1040
```

where the bounding box is explicit, in the `pdf:image` there is no bounding box, and the cropbox must be extracted from the PDF file. Do you know of some tool that extracts the cropbox safely? I tested `pdfinfo` and it produced the following code:

```
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.20
CreationDate:   Mon Aug 31 13:24:48 2020 CEST
ModDate:        Mon Aug 31 13:24:48 2020 CEST
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      347 x 426 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      11745 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Is the "Page size" actually the cropbox? And are "pts" PostScript points (= bp) or TeX points (= pt)?

Comment: the specials are (mostly) documented in the dvipdfm manual (`texdoc dvipdfm`) although looking at the source sometimes helps.... yes the PDF page boxes are given like a PostScript Bounding box in bp.

Comment: Normally 'multi-part' questions are not encouraged, but here I can see that everything is very closely tied, so it's probably OK

Comment: Thanks David. I got the dvipdfm manual, written in 1999 (!), it contains indeed the pdf namespace specials but not the x namespace ones. When I did `texdoc xdvipdfm` I got the man page of dvipdfmx, but it does not contain any information on specials. Does anyone know where I can find the specifications of the x-namespace specials?

Comment: @yannis I 'm not sure they've every been documented: they were used by Ross Moore in `xetex.def`, at least from around 2004 according to comments in (older) `xetex.def` versions. They've then been 'adopted' in `dvipdfmx.def` (they were not used in 2009, which is the earliest version that I've got immediately to hand).

Comment: The logs for `xetex.def` say `2004/05/08 Version v0.6 properly implements scaling and rotations`, so I'd guess around then, but one would need to check the `xdvipdfmx`/`xdv2pdf` sources (I guess from SIL) to track this down. Likely only Jonathan Kew can give a definitive answer.

Comment: The XeTeX Git repo only goes back to 2005, and the specials are in `xdv2pdf` from the start

Answer (score 4):

First, taking the general question, the `pdf:` specials are described in the `dvipdfm` and `dvipdfmx` manuals. For the latter, you want `dvipdfmx-special.pdf`, which I access using `texdoc -l dvipdfmx` as it's entry #2 in the list of files.

The `x:` versions are not (to my knowledge) documented - reading [the source](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipdfm-x/specials.c?revision=56121&view=markup), these originate from `xdvipdfmx`, but since `dvipdfmx` and `xdvipdfmx` are now merged, this is unimportant. The key is that they work the same as `pdf:...` versions documented for `dvipdfm`, and even more importantly we know that they've been used in that way for many years. So although these started off as XeTeX-specific, today we can intermix `pdf:` and `x:` specials with `dvipdfmx` as you've seen. (It is worth noting that they are implemented independently, so interactions should in general be tested.) There is some information on the XeTeX list about some of the specials, most obviously https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2004-May/000220.html.

The `btrans`/`etrans` pair form a scope for the transformation matrix. (In the `l3backend` version of the same code, we use `x:gsave`/`x:grestore`, which saves/restores the entire graphics state - that allows some code sharing with other operations.) The `btrans`/`etrans` pair are useful when one wants an explicit *paired* set of specials; contrast with `x:rotate` or similar, which is a 'one shot' operation so best suited to 'building up' *within* an outer `x:gsave`/`x:grestore` pair. (In the `l3backend` code we use both for this reason, as they match with the APIs from other backends.)

Using `x:scale`, etc., should I think be equivalent to using `pdf:brans scale`, as both let the backend 'track' transformations. This shows up for example when you have hyperlinks nested inside such a space: a raw call to a PDF `cm` operation will mean these get messed up. As noted above, the main difference between the two is that the `x:` version can be 'stand alone' inside a series of transformations, whereas `pdf:btrans` requires matching `pdf:etrans` operations.

On the question 'why scale twice', it's because you've got an image inside a scaled box. In XeTeX, we don't scale images 'directly' (at the level of the special to include the image), but rather we insert the image inside a box which is then scaled (this is shared with pdfTeX, see below). As such, when you include the image, it's set at full scale (no scaling as an optional argument to `\includegraphics`), and that shows up as the no-op scaling. You then scale a *surrounding* box, which is done in 'big points', hence the slightly strange values.

(With XeTeX, we could choose to scale the image at point-of-inclusion, but that doesn't work for `dvipdfmx` so to share code we avoid it. Essentially, newer backend code tends to follow pdfTeX, and the primitive it uses for image inclusion doesn't offer scaling for all image types, so the best shared code route is to scale a containing box.)

Finally, we turn to the bounding box. In the `dvipdfmx` route, we have to use the auxiliary program `extractbb` to get the bounding box. However, in XeTeX, we have an image primitive `\XeTeXpdffile`, which can read the PDF directly. It takes a keyword argument to say *which* box to read: this is covered in `texdoc xetex`. You'll see there that this primitive can do image scaling, in contrast to using `\special{pdf:image ...}`, but as noted above, that feature is not used. If one chose to scale/rotate the image at the `\XeTeXpdffile` level, this would show up in the `matrix`: I'm unsure in this case how well that interacts with hyperlinks.

Inserting a PDF image crops around the desired bounding box, meaning that you don't need to worry about the units. If you want to know the size of the resulting image, you measure the TeX box that it ends up in, for example

```latex
\setbox0=\hbox{\XeTeXpdffile "foo.pdf" media }%
\edef\pictureheight{\the\ht0 }%
\edef\picturewidth{\the\wd0 }%
```

as the image is always inserted at the reference point of the box with no depth. You'll see in `xetex.def` we use that to assume that the lower-left co-ordinates are always `(0,0)` (cf. `dvips`, where life is more 'interesting').

For bitmap graphics, the primitive `\XeTeXpicfile` is available and can insert the image without needing a bounding box in advance. As we've just seen with `\XeTeXpdffile`, as these primitives are aware of the bounding box of the images, they insert them into TeX with a 'real' size, so we can measure the results using a TeX box in all cases.

Comment: Whilst one could read the `graphics-def` file `xetex.def` for comments here, I think we have a lot more notes in the `l3backend` bundle as they are in `.dtx` format and basically have been used to collect up this type of information!

Comment: Jonathan Kew pointed me to http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/base/XeTeX-notes.pdf, which mentions the `x:` specials that were present in 2005 - some of them survive